# Search like in google play

Tags: android, searchview

How does google go about searching items in google play? I was trying to find out how to implement a search like that, but the closest thing I managed to find was [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), but that creates another activity, unlike google play, which seems only to perform a fragment transition. The reason I'm asking this is that my app uses mostly fragments durring the app flow and the only way I could think of to perform this would be using custom searchview...

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Want search with suggestions?

Comment: No that is not necessary, but it'd be great if I could get updates when it's content is updated (so I can update another view)

Comment: Try autoComplete text view if you want suggestions. And if you want updates with simple searched textView. Then use textChanged listeners.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is your answer. If you are looking for the complete tutorial then go through [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm).